# For how long the data I received from someone through MEGA is saved there?

Tags: mega

I have received 18 GB of data through MEGA, but have not checked it right now, so what if I download that data after 2 to 3 days? Will it be still there and I can download it or will it be removed from there? Can someone tell?

Answer (score 1):

Depends... If you received your 18GB package as a link and you added (imported) it to your account (storage) it will stay there forever so you can review it whenever you wish. If you didn't add it to your account (storage) then the link is valid until it gets invalidated. Invalidation happens when:

- the owner removes those files
- the owner makes those files private
- someones report it via DMCA for ownership violation and MEGA takes it down

Your question is mentioning 2-3 days... there is no timeout trigger only those 3 mentioned scenarios.